# How to find a package starting with a given string at packages.ubuntu.com?

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-website

I was trying to find a package named `libkf5kjs-dev`. Now I know the exact name of the package, but when I went to the search page at [`packages.ubuntu.com`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) I only knew that it started with the string `libkf5`. If I type this into the keyword field:

[image]

and press `"Search"`, I get a lot of results but none of them matches 
`libkf5kjs-dev`. What am I missing here? How should I search to get the correct package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the "libkf5" search keyword on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) returns:

> Your keyword was too generic, for optimizing reasons some results
>   might have been suppressed. Please consider using a longer keyword or
>   more keywords.

It looks like the website has an upper limit on the number of search results. I would suggest using `apt-file` (install using `sudo apt install apt-file`) instead to return all possible results:

```
$ apt-file search libkf5 | grep libkf5kjs-dev
libkf5kjs-dev: /usr/share/doc/libkf5kjs-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libkf5kjs-dev: /usr/share/doc/libkf5kjs-dev/copyright
libkf5kjs-dev: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libkf5kjs-dev
```

where you can see that `libkf5kjs-dev` can be found.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yeah `apt-file` is a great tool :)

Comment: `apt-cache search` or `apt search` would be better, since you don't need to search filenames and `apt-file` isn't installed by default.

Comment: Or just `apt list libkf5\*`. (This works properly because the `apt` command's `list` action [uses globs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html) rather than regular expressions.) `apt-file` is really for when one needs to list or search for what *files* packages provide, and it doesn't seem like a reasonable tool to use for this purpose. I suggest either including some of these other methods in your answer, including an explanation of why you think `apt-file` should be used, or both.

Comment: @EliahKagan Feel free to write your own answer as I may not have time to update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

#### Web interface

If you look closely you will see a message:

> Your keyword was too generic, for optimizing reasons some results might have been suppressed.
>   Please consider using a longer keyword or more keywords.

search for `libkf5k` and you'll find `libkf5kjs-dev`.

#### The reason

Since these kind of queries can easily be used to run DoS like attacks to the databases they're not supported by the web interface.

---

#### CLI

You can also use command line to search for packages specifically for your Ubuntu version (using regex):

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only ^libkf5 | grep js | grep dev
libkf5jsembed-dev - Embedded JS library for Qt
libkf5kjs-dev - Support for JS scripting in Qt applications
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks. I can also search for two words like this: `libkf5` and `js` if I don't know that there is a letter `k` after `libkf5`

Comment: Yeah, that's correct ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind opening a ~1.2MB webpage, the full list of packages of a given release can be viewed on https://packages.ubuntu.com. For example: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/allpackages?format=txt.gz
Then, just use your browser search feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind including everything in your `source.list`, [globbing](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man7/glob.7.html) with [something like](https://askubuntu.com/a/1181366/349837) this could work:

```sh
apt list "libkf5*"
```

`apt search` will include package description, which sometimes is not wanted:

```
list - list packages based on package names
search - search in package descriptions
show - show package details
install - install packages
reinstall - reinstall packages
remove - remove packages
autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages
update - update list of available packages
upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
full-upgrade - upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages
edit-sources - edit the source information file
satisfy - satisfy dependency strings
```